# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar Mercado Envíos con el Checkout Básico de Mercado Pago si los pedidos de mi cliente tienen más de 1 producto?

Tags: php, mercadopago

Tengo un ecommerce para el cual uso MercadoPago como gestor de pagos online y quiero usar Mercado Envios para el envío de mis ordenes.

Actualmente uso el siguiente código, pero al momento de ir a pagar no tengo opciones relacionadas a envíos (Que te soliciten la dirección por ejemplo):

```
<?php
$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        "title" => $description,
        "quantity" => $qty,
        "currency_id" => "ARS",
        "unit_price" => $price
        "shipments" => array(
            "mode" => "me2",
            "dimensions" => $sizing
        )
    )
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
?>
```

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, porfavor explica mejor el problema y el resultado esperado. No es claro cual es la pregunta en si. Salu2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonzalo,

Deberías colocar todos los productos dentro de una sola caja y dentro de tu preferencia de pago, incluir el siguiente fragmento con las dimensiones totales de la caja:

```
<?php
require_once ('mercadopago.php');
$mp = new MP('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET');

$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "title" => $description,
            "quantity" => $qty,
            "currency_id" => "ARS"
            "unit_price" => $price
        )
    ),
    "shipments" => array(
            "mode" => "me2",
            "dimensions" => $sizing  // alto x ancho x largo , peso
    )
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);

?>
```

[Acá](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/use-mercadoenvios/) podés encontrar más información

Saludos!

Comment: Matias Gordon yo tengo la misma consulta, ya que si en el carrito tengo mas de un producto, no se cual es el volumen sumado de los productos (ademas no es una simple suma) y en que caja corresponden para el calculo de costo de envio. Como se podria calcular el costo de envio de mas de un producto de la mejor manera? Saludos y Gracias [tag:MercadoPago] [tag:PHP]

Comment: Hola te aconsejo agregar otra pregunta donde especifiques detalles para acaparar la atención de expertos. Saludos.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/57239)

Comment: El comentario del buen Patricio Moracho es para @Titansol :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once ('mercadopago.php');

$mp = new MP('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET');

$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "title" => "Multicolor kite",
            "quantity" => 1,
            "currency_id" => "ARS", // Available currencies at: https://api.mercadopago.com/currencies
            "unit_price" => 10.00
        )
    ),
    "shipments" => array(
        "mode" => "me2",
        "dimensions" => "30x30x30,500",
        "local_pickup" => true,
        "free_methods" => array(
            array(
                "id" => 73328
            )
        ),
        "default_shipping_method" => 73328,
        "zip_code" => "5700"
    )
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pay</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="<?php echo $preference['response']['init_point']; ?>">Pay</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Trata de explicar un poco mas tu respuesta, el porque de lo que escribiste. No solo soltar el código asi nomas. Te invito a que leas [como escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).